# Multiple beans one button in jsf

Tags: javascript, jsf, javabeans

I have two managed beans, forms and its session scoped.

form1 button

```
<p:commandButton action="#{bean1.method1()}" ></p:commandButton>
```

form2 button

```
<p:commandButton action="#{bean2.method2()}" ></p:commandButton>
```

I only get one of the forms. "form2 value" is null. why?

```
 <script>          
              function submitOthers() {

                   document.getElementById("form1").submit();
                   document.getElementById("form2").submit();

                 }
    </script>

    <h:form id="form3">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" onclick="submitOthers()"/>           
    </h:form>
```

Comment: What is your usecase? This is a very uncommon way to do things (would not work well in plain html either). Why do you think you need multiple forms yet want to submit them with one button? Maybe 'ajax' is better way of solving your real problem.

Comment: Because i have different methods for saving to database, Button in forms includes methods, Can you give a specific example about it? Thx

Comment: Then make one method server-side and call two methods there... Way more simple